# Why does the electrostatic energy of a periodic array of charges diverge?

Tags: electrostatics

I am wondering if there is an intuitive way to explain why the energy of a periodic array of charges diverges.

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "periodic array"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are an infinite number of charges!

Comment: Perhaps just as importantly the per-charge energy remains finite, and so can be used in models of macroscopic collections.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question. Infinite sums can converge.

Comment: @BenCrowell Why are convergent infinite sums relevant to an infinite lattice where there are an infinite number of charges each with the *same* contribution to the total PE?

Comment: @dmckee Consider a simple 1D lattice of charges. Isn’t even the *per-charge* energy infinite since the sum of $1/n$ diverges?

Comment: Hmmm ... I believe you are correct.

Comment: And if the 1D sum diverges, the 2D and 3D cubic-lattice versions do as well.